# How do I upload/download a file to a facebook group

Tags: c#, facebook, download, upload, facebook-group

I can get list of all the files in my facebook group by doing a GET:

```
files = fb.Get(groupid + "/files");
```

But can anyone give me example in c# to upload a file to the group and also how to download a file (I can get downlink to the file from files list, but needs a browser to use it while I want to receive it within my appilcation and haven't figured out to use this download link)?

There is a lot of examples for pictures, but my need is for excel files, .txt files etc.

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/files you can't upload them. Use download_link to download them

Comment: Tried with this to download:
                 
string remote_uri = dl_fil.download_link;                
WebClient client = new WebClient();                
client.DownloadFile(remote_uri, filnavn);

but the file I get is not containing what the real file from group contains. What do I do wrong?

Comment: See if they work as a logged in Facebook user.

Comment: normal download works directly from the group. User is logged in before download in the program

Comment: I meant if you open the link in a web browser can you then download the file?

Comment: yes, that works fine as well. In my program it also download the file, but the contents is something http code from facebook and not the original content